# My Menu bar link is not working when i click it doesn't work

Tags: html, css

```css
.page-banner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; }
  .page-banner__bg-image {
    opacity: .33;
    height: 55vh;
    background-position: top;
    background-size: cover; }
  .page-banner__title {
    font-size: 5rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15rem;
    left: 21rem;
    text-transform: uppercase; }
  .page-banner__intro {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25rem;
    left: 21rem; }
    
    
.site_logo {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #3D566E;
  margin-left: 8rem;
  transform: translateY(2rem);
  text-decoration: none; }
  
  .navigation {
  height: 7.6rem;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #3D566E; }
  .navigation_menu {
    font-size: 2rem; }
    .navigation_menu-list {
      display: inline-block;
      float: right; }
      .navigation_menu-list li {
        display: inline-block;
        padding-right: 3rem;
        transform: translateY(-8px); }
        .navigation_menu-list li a {
          text-decoration: none; }
          .navigation_menu-list li a:hover {
            color: #0BBDAA; }

  .site_logo:hover {
    text-decoration: overline; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=`, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <section class="navigation">
    <div class="site_nav">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="index.html" class="site_logo">SCORILO</a>

        </div>
        <div class="navigation_menu">
            <nav class="navigation_menu-list">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="interior-page.html">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Programs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Campuses</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        
        
    </div>
    <div class="page-banner">
      <div class="page-banner__bg-image" style="background-image: url(https://piecubed.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/1280px-Clouds_over_the_Atlantic_OceanCROP.jpg);"></div>
      <div class="page-banner__content container container--narrow">
        <h1 class="page-banner__title">Our History</h1>
        <div class="page-banner__intro">
          <p>Learn how the school of your dreams got started.</p>
        </div>
      </div>  
      


</section>


      
</body>
</html>
```

My Nav menu href  link is not working. I was trying to create a about us page but after creating a page href link is not working even it is not detecting a menu as lnik . Please look on this
My Nav menu href  link is not working. I was trying to create a about us page but after creating a page href link is not working even it is not detecting a menu as lnik . Please look on this

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following element:

```
<div class="page-banner__bg-image" style="background-image: url(https://piecubed.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/1280px-Clouds_over_the_Atlantic_OceanCROP.jpg);"></div>
```

Is covering your menu so you can't click it. I've given it a lower `z-index` to send it back and made the navigation background transparent so that the image comes through.

```css
.page-banner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.page-banner__bg-image {
  opacity: .33;
  height: 55vh;
  background-position: top;
  background-size: cover;
}

.page-banner__title {
  font-size: 5rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15rem;
  left: 21rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.page-banner__intro {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25rem;
  left: 21rem;
}

.site_logo {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #3D566E;
  margin-left: 8rem;
  transform: translateY(2rem);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navigation {
  height: 7.6rem;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #3D566E;
}

.navigation_menu {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.navigation_menu-list {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

.navigation_menu-list li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 3rem;
  transform: translateY(-8px);
}

.navigation_menu-list li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navigation_menu-list li a:hover {
  color: #0BBDAA;
}

.site_logo:hover {
  text-decoration: overline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=`, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="navigation">
    <div class="site_nav">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="index.html" class="site_logo">SCORILO</a>

      </div>
      <div class="navigation_menu">
        <nav class="navigation_menu-list">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="interior-page.html">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Programs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Campuses</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>


    </div>
    <div class="page-banner">
      <div class="page-banner__bg-image" style="background-image: url(https://piecubed.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/1280px-Clouds_over_the_Atlantic_OceanCROP.jpg);"></div>
      <div class="page-banner__content container container--narrow">
        <h1 class="page-banner__title">Our History</h1>
        <div class="page-banner__intro">
          <p>Learn how the school of your dreams got started.</p>
        </div>
      </div>



  </section>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hello, It Worked Could you please explain me what is happening in background-color transparent ? Does nav has a default white color ?

Comment: @RameshAdhikari your original code in question have `.navigation {background-color: #FFFFFF;}` it'll create a white block on top of the image when it is send behind the navigation